# Map key + mouse click/movement to something on Linux

Tags: linux, xorg, xmodmap

When I was using OS X, I was able to remap left click + ctrl to right click and cursor movement + shift to scroll in the direction the cursor would be travelling. Is this possible on Linux?

Arch Linux with KDE Plasma 5.